# Cannot load jdbc driver class org.apache.hive.jdbc.hivedriver in Kylo

Tags: hive, apache-nifi, kylo

I am trying to create a Data Ingest Feed but all the jobs are failing. I checked Nifi and there are error marks saying that "org.apache.hive.jdbc.hivedriver" was not found. I checked the nifi logs and found the following error :

[image: Error found in Nifi log]

[image: Error found in Nifi]

So where exactly do I need to put the hivedriver jar?

Comment: Have you tried using a Data Transformation feed? The Data Ingest template is for loading data into Hive, but it looks like you're using it to move data from one Hive table into another.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying Greg.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, this seems to be the solution as mentioned by @Greg Hart:

> Have you tried using a Data Transformation feed? The Data Ingest
>   template is for loading data into Hive, but it looks like you're using
>   it to move data from one Hive table into another.